# Enemy (prefab) Behaviour messed up

Tags: unity, c#

I have created a prefab of an enemy with a NPC Behaviour script attached to it. The enemy correctly detects the player's position and walks (with animation) towards it (NavMesh Agent). If in range the enemy attacks the player until one of them dies. So far so good!

I duplicated the enemy in the scene a couple of times and the original enemy works as it should but the "replicas" completely ignore the player and just sit in Idle. What am I missing?

**[EDIT]** As requested in the comments:
This is how Character Health is assigned

```
//From my player script
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float health = 100f;

//SINGLETON and Assigning instance on Awake();

//yada yada

public void PlayerTookDamage(float damage)
    {
        if(health > 0f)
        {
            health -= damage;
            this.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("tookDamage");
        }
        else return;
    }

}
```

And this is from the NPC's script:

```
public class NpcBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private NavMeshAgent _agent;
    private static Animator _anim;
    private Transform _target;
    private float distanceFromTarget;
    private Vector3 direction;
    public float lookRadius = 10f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1.5f;

    void Start()
    {
        _target = PlayerScript.Instance.transform;
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _anim.SetBool("Idle", true);
        _agent = this.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(_target.position, transform.position);

        if (distance <= lookRadius && PlayerScript.Instance.health > 0f)
            {
                _anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
                _agent.SetDestination(_target.position);            
                _anim.SetBool("Idle", false);

                FaceTarget();

                if (distance <= _agent.stoppingDistance && cooldown <=0f)
                {
                    _anim.SetBool("Walk", false); 
                    Attack(); //just reduces player's health
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _agent.isStopped = true;
                _anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
                _anim.SetBool("Idle", true);
            }
    }
```

Comment: How is distance calculated? What is lookRadius set to? How is characterhealth assigned?

Comment: Did you click 'Apply to prefab' after attaching your script (or anim) to the first NPC?  If not, select the prefab in the project window and attach the script there, then save.  That will prevent your duplicates from losing their positions you have already set.

Comment: Yes I've clicked on apply. @ed That's not relevant since it works on the 'original' prefab. The point is why the 'duplicates' don't work.

Comment: Actually it may be relevant. Obviously something is different between the original and the duplicates, and that difference may be that somehow the variables upon which those calculations rely are not getting copied.

Comment: @EdMarty I 've edited the question and provided what you 've asked for.

Comment: I can't find where you define `_agent` in `NpcBehaviour` class.

Comment: When do you populate PlayerScript.Instance? Is it possible the copies are getting their Start() before it's had a chance to initialize, and fail to get the correct target?

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin in the Start() method.

Comment: @DMGregory PlayerScript.Instance is populated on Awake(). The copies check for the target at their Start() so this is not the issue. UPDATE: debugged the target; it is set to player. So the copies can "see" the target (PlayerScript.Instance) but "choose" to ignore it!?

Comment: [I downvoted this question because it fails to provide an MVCE.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `_anim` as static. This means that every copy is going to be modifying a single instance’s animator (the last one `start`ed). Simply removing the `static` keyword may fix the problem.

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal! That did it, thank you! (Honestly I don't even remember why I declared it as a static variable in the first place.)